# HACER UN INSERT EN SQL SERVER 2019 SI CUMPLE CONDICION

Tags: sql-server, condiciones, validación, insert, registro

Hola muy buenas tardes soy nuevo en el foro, he buscado referencias con respecto a mi problema y agradezco mucho me puedan ayudar con el siguiente...

Estoy intentando realizar un procedimiento almacenado que realice una inserción de un registro de incapacidad, pero antes necesito validar si el **NUMERO DE DOCUMENTO** de mi usuario, **FECHA DE INICIO** y **FECHA FINAL** ya existen en mi registro.

Si no existe el registro con los datos antes mencionados, entonces que haga la inserción de lo contrario que no haga nada.

A continuación dejaré mi código:

ALTER PROC [dbo].[INCAPACIDAD_INSERTAR]

```
@NUMEROID VARCHAR (20),
@CODIGO_CIE VARCHAR (10),
@FECHA_INICIO DATE,
@FECHA_FINAL DATE,
@EPS VARCHAR (100),
@TIPO_INC VARCHAR (10),
@USUARIO_RESPONSABLE VARCHAR (100),
@NOMBRE_PC VARCHAR (100),
@FECHA_REG DATE,
@SEXO VARCHAR (10)

AS

DECLARE @CODREGISTRO VARCHAR (20) 
DECLARE @NOMBREEMPLEADO VARCHAR (200)
DECLARE @CARGO VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @DESCRIPCION_CIE VARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @DIAS INT = DATEDIFF(DAY, @FECHA_INICIO, @FECHA_FINAL) +1
DECLARE @ULTIMOID INT

SELECT @NOMBREEMPLEADO = PRIMER_NOMBRE +' '+ PRIMER_APELLIDO +' '+ SEGUNDO_APELLIO FROM EMPLEADO WHERE NUM_DOCUMENTO=@NUMEROID
SELECT @DESCRIPCION_CIE = DESCRIPCION FROM CIE_10 WHERE COD_CIE_10 = @CODIGO_CIE
SELECT @SEXO = SEXO FROM EMPLEADO WHERE NUM_DOCUMENTO=@NUMEROID

SELECT @ULTIMOID = MAX (ID) FROM INCAPACIDADES
SET @CODREGISTRO = CONCAT ('INC-000A' , SUM (@ULTIMOID +1))

-----ESATA ES LA PARTE DONDE SE VALIDA SI EL REGISTRO QUE SE VA INGRESAR YA EXISTE------
DECLARE @VALIDACION BIT
SELECT @VALIDACION = CAST(CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) 
FROM INCAPACIDADES 
WHERE  ID = @NUMEROID AND FECHA_INICIO = @FECHA_INICIO AND FECHA_FINAL=@FECHA_FINAL 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

INSERT INCAPACIDADES (COD_REGISTRO, ID_AUSENTE, 
NOMBRE_EMPLEADO,CARGO,SEXO,TIPO_INCAPACIDAD, 
COD_DIAGNOSTICO,DESCRIPCION_DIAGNOSTICO,FECHA_INICIO,FECHA_FINAL,
DIAS_INCAPACIDAD,EPS,FECHA_REGISTRO,USUARIO_RESPONSABLE, NOMBRE_PC)

VALUES (@CODREGISTRO,@NUMEROID, @NOMBREEMPLEADO,@CARGO,@SEXO,@TIPO_INC, @CODIGO_CIE,@DESCRIPCION_CIE, 
@FECHA_INICIO,@FECHA_FINAL,
@DIAS,@EPS,@FECHA_REG,@USUARIO_RESPONSABLE,@NOMBRE_PC)
```

Comment: Puedes usar un `IF @VALIDACION = 1 ...  insertar registro`

Comment: Que sencillo jajajaja, no colocaría nada en el ELSE?

Comment: Tal vez `ELSE Select 'No existe' as MensajeError`?